# Write new Data in Android Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase Database in an Android application, and  everytime a user is registred I store some values in the database for this purpose I am doing what follows:

```
database =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                            DatabaseReference mRef =  database.getReference().child("Users").push();
                            FirebaseUser user =  mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            String userId = user.getUid();
                            mRef.child("User").child("age").setValue(selectedAge);
                            mRef.child("User").child("gender").setValue(finalGender);
                            mRef.child("User").child("userId").setValue(userId);
                            mRef.child("User").child("username").setValue(username);
```

but when I go to my firebase console I see that a kind of id is automaticaly generated which I do not need since as you can see in the image I set my own id.

[image]

Is there a way to avoid this, and create nodes like the second User node in the image ??

**NOTE**: the second user node i added it manualy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To directly answer your question here is the change I'd suggest:

```
FirebaseDatabase database =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
FirebaseUser user =  mAuth.getCurrentUser();
String userId = user.getUid();
DatabaseReference mRef =  database.getReference().child("Users").child(userId);
mRef.child("age").setValue(selectedAge);
mRef.child("gender").setValue(finalGender);
mRef.child("username").setValue(username);
```

I'd also suggest that you create a Java class to represent whatever user data you want to store in your database. Taking advantage of Firebase's ability to read/write to your database using Java classes will make those operations much easier. For example you add a `User` class to your project like the following:

```
public class User {

    public double age;
    public String gender;
    public String userName;

    //required default constructor
    public User() {
    }

    public User(double age, String gender, String userName) {
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public double getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(double age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}
```

By using a java class to write to your database you can update your write operation like so:

```
FirebaseDatabase database =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(); 
FirebaseUser user =  mAuth.getCurrentUser();
String userId = user.getUid();
User user = new User(26, "M", "user001");
DatabaseReference mRef =  database.getReference().child("Users").child(userId);
mRef.setValue(user);
```

Notice there is no field to the store user's `uid` in the Java object. This is up to you but I did not include it for two reasons. First, in the database we are using the user's `uid` as the key to store there data in a unique location. Second, since you are using Firebase Authentication, in your app if you need to get the id of the currently signed in user you can access it via `FirebaseAuth`.

Comment: Thank you very much, in the line: DatabaseReference mRef =  database.getReference().child("Users").child(userID);

I think you mean userId right ??
because I cannot see where userID is declared.

Comment: OK, thanks i have an other problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550149/check-if-user-is-authtificated-for-first-time-in-firebase-google-authentificatio, 
if you could have any idea

Answer (score 2):

Just change this line:

```
DatabaseReference mRef =  database.getReference().child("Users").push();
```

to this:

```
DatabaseReference mRef =  database.getReference().child("Users");
```

The push() automatically adds a unique key.

Comment: when i make the change, it does not create a new User node it overwrites the existing one.

Comment: This makes sense because as your code is now, you are telling Firebase to write the child information at Users -> User each time. Please take a look at the answer from Kevin O'Neil and try to implement it like that.