# Check if user is authenticated for the first time in Firebase Google Authentication in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Authentication in an Android application, and I am using Google account authentication as an option to sign in to the application.

How can I know if the user is signed in to the application for the first time or not?

Comment: So you want to use retrieve a list of all user using Firebase Auth?

Comment: yes it is exactly what I am looking for

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use Firebase Auth in that manner. You would have to follow what @NarenderReddy says - each time a user logs in for the first time you'll need to store some kind of entry using the Firebase Database (or your preferred storage method) along with the info you want to track. Then you can use that database location to get a list of all users.

Comment: OK, as you know everytime a user is registred in my app I store an ID for him, but the problem is that i am not able to make a query on the database, when the user is signing in, i only found examples with the dataSnapshot childEventListener, this is why I asked an other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552168/make-a-query-on-firebase-databse-for-android

Answer (score 62, accepted):

To check if it's the first time user logs in, simply call the `AdditionalUserInfo.isNewUser()` method in the `OnCompleteListener.onComplete` callback.

Example code below, be sure to check for null.

```
OnCompleteListener<AuthResult> completeListener = new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                boolean isNew = task.getResult().getAdditionalUserInfo().isNewUser();
                Log.d("MyTAG", "onComplete: " + (isNew ? "new user" : "old user"));
            }
        }
    };
```

Check the docs for more reference [`AdditionalUserInfo`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo)

Comment: It's not working, I declared it under onCreate() but it's never ran

Comment: @Sandeep can you be more specific of what's not working. Some code snippets would also be very helpful

Comment: @erict how to do it in flutter ?

Comment: @puzzled In Flutter, you can grab result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser property from AuthResult.

Answer (score 18):

From the [Firebase-ui docs](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth), you can check the last sign-in timestamp against the created-at timestamp like this:

```
FirebaseUserMetadata metadata = auth.getCurrentUser().getMetadata();
if (metadata.getCreationTimestamp() == metadata.getLastSignInTimestamp()) {
    // The user is new, show them a fancy intro screen!
} else {
    // This is an existing user, show them a welcome back screen.
}
```

Comment: It's possibly a Firebase bug - check a related post here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48079683/1145905

Comment: but it show the fancy intro screen after refresh the page too. i don't want to show the fancy intro screen after refresh.

Comment: These were returning 2 milliseconds apart for me for Google sign-in, it's not reliable. It was only working as intended for email authentication.

Comment: Agreeing with  @Anthony.  This does not work with google sign in.

Comment: I've tried it with Flutter phone auth, there is difference between the timestamps for the user just created.

Answer (score 8):

According to the new version of **Firebase auth (16.0.1)** The AuthResult class has a member function which results true or false (is the user is new). **Assuming "credential" is defined in the scope(it is the google credential )**. An example is shown below:
`

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
GoogleSignInAccount acct = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);

mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "linkWithCredential:success");


                        boolean newuser = task.getResult().getAdditionalUserInfo().isNewUser();



                        if(newuser){

                             //Do Stuffs for new user

                         }else{

                            //Continue with Sign up 
                        }

                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(MyClass.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }


            });
```

**Thanks to firebase:)**

Comment: not working it's always going to the 'Sign up' condition

Answer (score 6):

For **Web**, version 9.0 (**modular**):

You will need to import "getAdditionalUserInfo" and call it as such:

```
signInWithPopup(firebaseAuth, provider)
  .then((result) => {
    const details = getAdditionalUserInfo(result)
    console.log(details.isNewUser);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

The details returned includes an "**isNewUser**" boolean property.

[Details on GitHub from August 2021](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5257#issuecomment-895319041)

Answer (score 4):

From version 11.6.0  we can use `AdditionalUserInfo.isNewUser()`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo

Answer (score 2):

Workaround I used-

1. Created a collection in Firestore named 'Users'.
2. Whenever someone signs in, get its uid
3. Search for that uid in the 'Users'. Make sure to name 'Users' documents = user's UID.
4. If the document exists, then its the new user, if it doesn't
5. then add that particular user's doc in that collection 'Users'.

Trick Used - Use UID to solve this problem.
Thanks, upvote if helpful

Answer (score 1):

**A solution when you use Firebase Auth together with Firestore**

The root architecture of the Firestore Database would look like this
[image]

Use the Firebase Auth `currentUser.uid` to create a root document for each user. Start by adding a field called `registered_at` to the root document as soon as the user is created the first time and then add your specific collections to your root document depending on your use case.

When logging in or signing in you can then check if the document with the `registered_at` field already exists. If it doesn't exist yet, then you can treat the user as a new user (assuming the user can not delete or alter the `registered_at` field later)

```
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore

fun rootDocument(): DocumentReference? = rootPath()?.let {
    return fireStore().document(it)
}

fun rootPath(): String? {
    val loggedInUser = loggedInUser()
    if (loggedInUser != null) {
        return "users/${loggedInUser.uid}"
    }
    return null
}

fun fireStore() = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

fun createWriteBatch() = fireStore().batch()

fun loggedInUser() = fireAuth().currentUser

fun fireAuth(): FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

fun afterSignIn() {

    val rootDocument = rootDocument()
            ?: throw IllegalStateException("root document not found")

    rootDocument.get().addOnCompleteListener {
        val isNewUser = it.result.exists().not()

        if (isNewUser) {
            val batch = createWriteBatch()

            batch.set(rootDocument, HashMap<Any, Any>().apply {
                put("registered_at", System.currentTimeMillis())
            })

            batch.commit().addOnCompleteListener {
                println("this is a new user")
            }

        } else {
            println("this is not a new user")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While I fully agree that the most correct way (given the inability to add new fields to the auth user table) is to create a new path for users and store info there, I didn't want to make an additional request after logging in to do this check (I'm using Firestore and requests = money).

I needed to do this first login check to prompt for a userName (as display name is pulled from Facebook/Google and I wanted to give the option of overriding if it's their first login). What I ended up doing was using the photoURL property as a flag to determine if  it was their first time or not. It's not ideal but maybe someone that wants to save on requests can use this as a workaround. It's not as big a deal for Firebase but for Firestore it's more costly for your plan

Answer (score 1):

In Firebase UI, JAVA:

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Intent i;


        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


                if(response.isNewUser()){
                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: isNewUser "+response.isNewUser());
} else {

                // Successfully signed in
                }

                // ...
            } else {



//               handle error
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Firebase V9** (modular)

Here is a function that worked for me

```
function isNewUser(auth) {
    let newUser;
    const metadata = auth.currentUser.metadata;
    if (metadata.creationTime == metadata.lastSignInTime) {
      newUser = true;
    } else {
      newUser = false;
    }
    return newUser;
  }
```

You could use a shorter way:

```
  function isNewUser(auth) {
    const metadata = auth.currentUser.metadata;
    return metadata.creationTime == metadata.lastSignInTime ? true : false;
  }
```

I have seen something similar that uses functions on the metadata like `metadata.getCreationTimeStamp()` but that did not work for me.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This may help you and try it:

[Correct code location to check Firebase if a user has been created already?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35285856/correct-code-location-to-check-firebase-if-a-user-has-been-created-already)

Comment: @adityashrivastava Your SO question refers to the Firebase database (Realtime Database) the user has set. wants to be able to solve it only with Firebase (Authentication)

Answer (score 0):

*First of all Check - if current user uid match with your documents id then it's old user otherwise it's new user*

> Example

```
private boolean isUserMatch(String currentUserId) {
    firestore.collection(COLLECTION_USER).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener< QuerySnapshot >() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task< QuerySnapshot > task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                    if (currentUserId.equals(documentSnapshot.getId())) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull @NotNull Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ", e.getCause());
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```