# Firebase user returns null metadata for already signed up users

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have been using Firebase for authentication of users in the app. `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getMetadata()` returns `null` when user comes back to the app after the sign up. It works perfectly when user signs up for the first time, but returns `null` for returning users.

Comment: Suggest you contact [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/).  This appears to be an undocumented limitation or bug.  I thought calling [FirebaseUser.reload()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) might help, but still get null metadata.

Comment: @BobSnyder Just posted a request to Firebase Support. I am not sure if they will pay a serious attention as I have an issue pending with them already.

Comment: This appears to be a bug. I have filed a report with Firebase Auth team. If you need to check if a user is new or existing, use https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo.html#isNewUser() for now, available from AuthResult.

Comment: @bojeil I am using a workaround by storing the state in SharedPreferences. BTW, `AdditionalUserInfo` object holds IDP-specific data for the user if the provider is one of Facebook, Github, Google, or Twitter. In my case the provider is Phone Number. Have a look at the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo#isNewUser())

Comment: @bojeil Also, I am using `AuthStateListener` to listen to changes in the auth state. I don't see a way to get the reference to `AuthResult` in `AuthStateListener` implementation.

Comment: It should also return that for phone number sign in as an `AuthResult` is also returned there. You can't get that from `AuthStateListener`. You have to get it when the sign in task resolves.

Comment: @bojeil You are partially right here. `AuthResult` is returned for the Phone Number provider also, _Correct_. `isNewUser()` will work, _Incorrect_. To call `isNewUser()`, I need `AdditionalUserInfo` reference which can be obtained by calling `getAdditionalUserInfo() ` on `AuthResult` reference but the problem is `getAdditionalUserInfo() ` will return [IDP-specific information for the user if the provider is one of Facebook, Github, Google, or Twitter.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AuthResult.html#getAdditionalUserInfo())

Comment: It seems like that is a bug too. `AdditionalUserInfo` should not be null, `getProfile` should be null in that case (phone auth). I will file this report with Firebase Auth.

Answer (score 4):

Malcolm from the Firebase Team here.

Thanks for pointing this out. This is presently a bug in the persistence done by the Android SDK. We'll get on fixing this ASAP - keep an eye on upcoming release notes to know when it's resolved.

In the meantime, the workaround you can use is to write to your app's [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) to store those attributes at sign up time, and read from those Prefs when you need them elsewhere in your app. Hope this helps!

Comment: By asking this question to Firebase Support, I have reduced my quota of support questions by one. Now that it is a known bug, can you please update my Firebase Support questions quota by transferring the question under bugs and feature requests. I think it's a fair request. :)

Comment: Is that resolved now? There is no issue link provided!!

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue with getMetadata() returning null.

I had added Firebase support in Android Studio using the Firebase Assistant wizard.  I just could not get FirebaseUser.getMetadata() to work.

Then I updated the build.gradle (Module: app) dependencies as follows:

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

(These were the latest versions at the time of this writing.  By the time you read this, there may be even newer versions)

I found that I still got null but then I went to add a new user and all of a sudden it started working. I had deleted all existing accounts and created new ones - don't know if that made a difference.  But it seems to be working now.

So - updating the dependencies and doing a gradle sync may fix your problem, at least for new users.

The Firebase Assistant in Android Studio probably needs to be modified to reflect the latest versions.

(Still worried about about this being completely reliable..)