# How to resolve Nullpointer exception after user logs in for the second time in Firebase app?

Tags: android, firebase, nullpointerexception, firebase-authentication

When an email verified user logs in for the first time in my app everything works as expected (he gets to a welcome screen and then to the MainActivity) but when he logs out out and logs in again there is a null pointer exception. When a user logs in for the second time he should go straight to the MainActivity and not to the welcome screen which you see in the below code.

This was a known issue about a year ago so my question is how to resolve this issue? Has this bug been fixed and when yes what did I do wrong in my code?

The question I am referring is here :[Firebase user returns null metadata for already signed up users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079683/firebase-user-returns-null-metadata-for-already-signed-up-users)

Here is the code I am using to check whether the user logs in for the first or second time:

```
...

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();

        if (firebaseUser != null && firebaseUser.isEmailVerified()) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginEmailActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_email_login);

        ...

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ...

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                final FirebaseUserMetadata metadata = auth.getCurrentUser().getMetadata();

                //authenticate user
                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(LoginEmailActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginEmailActivity.this, "Ups, es ist wohl etwas schief gelaufen. Bitte überprüfe deine Internetverbindung und versuche es erneut.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                } else {

                                    if (auth.getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified() && !(metadata.getCreationTimestamp() == metadata.getLastSignInTimestamp())){
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginEmailActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();

                                    } else if (auth.getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified() && (metadata.getCreationTimestamp() == metadata.getLastSignInTimestamp())){

                                        firstLoginScreen();
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                    else if (!auth.getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified()){
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginEmailActivity.this, "Bitte verifiziere erst deine E-Mail Adresse mit dem Link, den wir dir geschickt haben.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });

...
```

Here is the error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUserMetadata com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getMetadata()' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.android.guessit.LoginRegistration.LoginEmailActivity$1.onClick

Also the "getCreationTimestamp" says that it may produce a NullPointerException

Comment: Can you share your nullpointer stacktrace? Probably in `FirebaseUser firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser()` auth is null but not sure without looking at the error

Comment: I edited my question, now having the error

Comment: @Daniel I saw that you reverted from my edit. Errors should be formatted as blockquotes and not as code. That's the reason for the edit in the first place

Comment: In `auth.getCurrentUser()` the current user is null. So you don't actually have a user to query for its metadata.

Comment: I create the user when he registers with his mail so this shouldn't be null. I can see that the user is registered in firebase under "Authentication" even before he verifies his email. The user can login for the first time and everything works without exception, only when he logs out and in again he gets a null pointer exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is where you call

```
final FirebaseUserMetadata metadata = auth.getCurrentUser().getMetadata()
```

Calling it before completing the user login, brings you to the NullPointer you are facing. Just move it inside the `onComplete` callback, where the `current user` has a value.

Also, just for code optimisation add a return statement when you switch to the MainActivity.

```
if (firebaseUser != null && firebaseUser.isEmailVerified()) {
     startActivity(new Intent(LoginEmailActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
     finish();
     return;
}
```

You need a return in your if statement when you go to the MainActivity. Otherwise after that you set again `setContentView(R.layout.activity_email_login)`.

Comment: Isn't `finish()` meant to close the running process? I mean, this looks like tautology in some sense.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve my problem. I get the same error again. As stated in my question this has been a known bug more than a year ago, so I was wondering if this is an expected result because the firebase didn't fix that problem yet or its something with my code

Comment: @TaslimOseni finish() starts the process to "kill" the activity context but still the code after it is executed and also you will have onStop() and onDestroy() callbacks. @Daniel indeed your problem is the null pointer when you get the user's metadata. Putting a return after finish is an optimisation of your code but the problem is when you have null metadata. Maybe move the `final FirebaseUserMetadata metadata = auth.getCurrentUser().getMetadata()` inside the `onComplete` callback

Comment: @Robert Yes this solved my problem. If you post this as a separate answer I can mark this topic as resolved

Comment: Changed my answer. Glad it helped you

Comment: What does return do, why does it optimize the code?

Comment: It returns from the onCreate method. So all the code after is not executed. Since you change context and you go to the MainActivity you don't need to set the content view and the login click listener. Your code still works if you don't call it, but since you are finishing the welcome activity, it is useless to execute the rest of the code

Comment: So it makes the app faster?

Comment: A bit more fore sure. In this case very very few milliseconds. But if in an app you have many situations like this, then you will have some better performance.