# How to get AuthResult in flutter Firebase UI to find additionalUserInfo

Tags: authentication, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am new to flutter and using [sample code](https://medium.com/flutterpub/firebase-ui-with-flutter-ccd6d4d6807) that does signIn, I get the user, but I need to find if the user has previously used the App ( and then uninstalled) or using on a new device. I see another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51819652/check-if-user-is-new-using-firebase-authentication-in-flutter/57363643#57363643) that gets the AuthResult as shown below,

```
AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  if (authResult.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
    //User logging in for the first time
    // Redirect user to tutorial 
  }
  else {
    //User has already logged in before.
    //Show user profile
  }
```

But the [SignInScreen](https://medium.com/flutterpub/firebase-ui-with-flutter-ccd6d4d6807), does not return the authResult

```
SignInScreen(
        title: "Demo",
        header: new Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
          child: new Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: new Text("Demo"),
          ),
        ),
        showBar: true,
        // horizontalPadding: 8,
        bottomPadding: 5,
        avoidBottomInset: true,
        color: Color(0xFF363636),
        providers: [
          ProvidersTypes.google,
          ProvidersTypes.phone,
          ProvidersTypes.facebook,
        //  ProvidersTypes.twitter,
        //  ProvidersTypes.email
        ],
        twitterConsumerKey: "",
        twitterConsumerSecret: "", horizontalPadding: 12,
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the [code](https://github.com/fidelisa/flutter_plugins/blob/2493c244b123ec217aebec7efbbeaf934cd4b2f2/packages/flutter_firebase_ui/lib/login_view.dart#L57), it looks like the `firebase-ui-flutter` library that you're using does not expose the user from the active sign-in operation (calls to `signInWith...`).

You'll either have to update the library to expose the functionality, write your own sign-in UI, or find another library that handles it better. You could also [file a bug on the repo](https://github.com/fidelisa/flutter_plugins/issues), but it's seen very little maintenance in the past two years. There's a [fork](https://github.com/Maliffic/firebase_ui/) that seems more update, but that [code](https://github.com/Maliffic/firebase_ui/blob/0d47641ba430dd9fb1ecde438a96a4d62c86ec49/lib/login_view.dart#L55) also doesn't expose the result from active sign-in.

Comment: thanks, Is there a concept of 3rd party libraries and original( i.e Google's official) libraries in Flutter and if there is any original library that does the task of Login/Registration or any example that you can point to ?