# Check if the Firebase user is authenticated for the first time using google in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

In my app, I'm authenticating users with **Google** sign in. How to check if the user is signing in for the first time?

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550149/check-if-user-is-authenticated-for-the-first-time-in-firebase-google-authenticat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the user is signing in for the first time, the [`AdditionalUserInfo.isNewUser` property](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/AdditionalUserInfo-class.html) will be true.

Note that this property can be a bit finicky in my experience as "first" is a bit too strict. If that is the case for you, you might want to instead compare the `creationTime` and `lastSigninTime` in the [`FirebaseUserMetaData` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseUserMetadata-class.html) explicitly to determine whether the user is "new enough".

Comment: Thanks! Solved it by comparing creationTimestamp and lastSignInTimestamp. But in my project, unable to access some classes like  AdditionalUserInfo, AuthResult etc. Can you please explain it?