# Flutter: How to get additional info from user after signing up?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart, firebase-authentication

In my flutter app I'm using **phone verification** method to sign the user up, however I'm not sure how to ask newly signed up user about his additional info in next screen which is in my case - Full Name, email and address etc.

I'm using **firebase realtime db** as backend, *how do I store and retrieve* this additional info of user in my app? Can someone give me any idea or supporting material to implement this? 
Thank YOU.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a page that checks if the user is authenticated, and if so create a form that will allow to user to enter the additional information required.

You can then assign this data to the user via the `updateProfile()` and the `updateEmail()` methods.

More information can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users).

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550149/check-if-user-is-authenticated-for-the-first-time-in-firebase-google-authenticat) question to find out how to check if the user has logged in for the first time.