# Check if user is authenticated for the first time with Firebase phone Authentication in Android

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I need to detect and differentiate two users using **Firebase phone authentication**. This should be done before granting a privilege to enter into the **home activity** of the app. When I did as suggested [here (Stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50212276/9942927), it does well by detecting the user using `timeStamp()` method. The answer does its job but the fancy thing is I need some data input from the new user before the verification code is sent.

In order for a verification code to be sent, a user provides a number which is directly authenticated in the `firebase`. Hence I cannot check if it's a `new user` (phone number) or `current user` (phone number).

Here is the code using **`TimeStamp()`** method.

```
private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential)
{
    _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), task ->
    {
        if(task.isSuccessful())
        {
            //Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information.
            FirebaseUser _user = Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).getUser();
            long creationTimestamp = Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.requireNonNull(_user).getMetadata()).getCreationTimestamp();
            long lastLoginTimestamp = Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.requireNonNull(_user).getMetadata()).getLastSignInTimestamp();

            if(creationTimestamp == lastLoginTimestamp)
            {
                //Create a new user with account
                setUserDataToDatabase(_user, _username, _university, _course, _year);
                sendUserToWelcome();
            }
            else
            {
                //User exists, just login
                sendUserToHome();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            FancyToast.makeText(getContext(), "Enter sent code", FancyToast.LENGTH_SHORT, FancyToast.INFO, false).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After several research with no success. I decided to walk around, I'm using `firestore database`. I decided to track every user's number in a new `collection` with auto-generated `document id`. I called the collection **`USERS`** whereas each `document` has a unique random id.

I get the user's number and check it if any of the registered user has that number with the **`USERS`**'s collection using a `whereEqualTo()` method with the **`phone_number`** field. `If` the number is exists I login the user `else` display a registration screen.

```
 _firestore.collection(USERS).whereEqualTo("phone_number", _phoneCheck).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task)
                        {
                            if(task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                //If task is greater than 0 means there is a presence of a phone number.
                                if(Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).size() > 0)
                                {
                          
                                //Here I allow user to login as usual.
                                PhoneAuthOptions options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(_firebaseAuth).setPhoneNumber(_phone).setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS).setActivity(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).setCallbacks(_callbacks).build();
                                PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
                                }
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                //Else the task is empty means there is no a presence of a phone number.

                                //Check if there is a presence of registration data to bind with new user.
                                if(_registrationData != null)
                                {
             
                                    //I login user with the new data and save the information into the firestore plus the phone number.
                                    PhoneAuthOptions options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(_firebaseAuth).setPhoneNumber(_phone).setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS).setActivity(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).setCallbacks(_callbacks).build();
                                    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
                                    userInputs();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //Display a welcome a screen to register an account.
                                    FancyToast.makeText(getContext(), "Welcome! Open an account", FancyToast.LENGTH_SHORT, FancyToast.INFO, false).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Allowing unauthenticated user to have a privilege into the database is very risk. Hence, I implemented a rule to allow unauthenticated user to read only.

```
match /USERS/{document=**}
{
    allow read: if true;
}
```

Though this still is risky, any rule suggestions I will be grad and appreciable.